# Mongoose is not showing the ISODate in the result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0, node.js

I am using mongodb version `4.2.2`.

I have following data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c58089c058304f7a64fa9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-07-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 0,
    "staffMember" : ObjectId("5f0c58076b559419d62efe47"),
    "startTime" : 885
},

/* 2 createdAt:2020-07-13T12:48:08.000Z*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c58089c058304f7a64fa8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-07-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 0,
    "staffMember" : ObjectId("5f0c58076b559419d62efe47"),
    "startTime" : 870
},

/* 3 createdAt:2020-07-13T12:48:08.000Z*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c58089c058304f7a64fa7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-07-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 0,
    "staffMember" : ObjectId("5f0c58076b559419d62efe47"),
    "startTime" : 855
},

/* 4 createdAt:2020-07-13T12:48:08.000Z*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c58089c058304f7a64fa6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-07-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 0,
    "staffMember" : ObjectId("5f0c58076b559419d62efe47"),
    "startTime" : 840
}
```

I am using `mongoose` in my project. When I run this query in node js:

```
const { memberId, date } = req.params;
let isoDate = date.toISOString();
let timeSlots = await TimeSlots.find(
{
  staffMember: memberId,
  date: isoDate 
});
```

The result printed on the `console`:

```
db.spaTimeSlots.find({"staffMember" : ObjectId("5f0c58076b559419d62efe47"), date: new Date("Wed, 11 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT")})
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

However, I want this result:

```
db.spaTimeSlots.find({"staffMember" : ObjectId("5f0c58076b559419d62efe47"), date: ISODate("2021-07-11T00:00:00.000Z")})
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

I want the result returned with the date in `ISODate` format, not as text (i.e. not `Wed, 11 Jul`).

Comment: This question should have been asked on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add like this:

```
let date = new Date().toISOString();
let isoDate = new Date(date);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`ISODate` is a `mongo` shell type, it does not exist in Node.

You can format the JS `Date` object any way you wish in your application.

Comment: Actually `ISODate()` is synonym for Javascript `new Date()`, i.e.it **is** a `Date` object.